# Setting up a chart that displays the number of times a dataset record appears in C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, charts, dataset

I am trying to create a chart that when, at the push of a button displays a chart that shows the user the number of times a record has appeared in the dataset/table that it is linked to. Please bare in mind that I have little experience with using Charts in Visual Studios/C#.

Currently I am getting this error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVL51.png)

This is all the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace RRAS
{
    public partial class formRRAS : Form
    {
        public OleDbConnection DataConnection = new OleDbConnection();

        public formRRAS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void formRRAS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.tblReject_test' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblReject_testTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This creates the String Publisher which grabs the information from the combo box on the form.
            //Select and Dataconnection are also defined here.
            string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
                string DataConnection;
                string Department = txtDepartment.Text;
                string Start_Date = txtStart.Text;
                string End_Date = txtEnd.Text;
                string Anatomy = txtAnatomy.Text;
                string RFR = cmbRFR.Text;
                string Comment = txtComment.Text;

            //Select defines what should be loaded on to the dataset.
            if (Department != "")
            {
                Select = Select + " WHERE department_id =" + "'" + Department + "'";

                if (Anatomy != "")
                {
                    Select = Select + "AND body_part_examined =" + "'" + Anatomy + "'";

                    if (Start_Date != "")
                    {
                        Select = Select + " AND study_date =" + "'" + Start_Date + "'";

                        if (End_Date != "")
                        {
                            Select = Select + " AND study_date =" + "'" + End_Date + "'";

                            if (RFR != "")
                            {
                                Select = Select + " AND reject_category =" + "'" + RFR + "'";

                                if(Comment != "")
                                {
                                    Select = Select + " AND reject_comment =" + "'" + Comment + "'";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
            }
            //DataConnection connects to the database.
            string connectiontring= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
            DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

            //The DataAdapter is the code that ensures both the data in the Select and DataConnection strings match.
            OleDbDataAdapter rdDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select, DataConnection);

            try
            {
                //It then clears the datagridview and loads the data that has been selected from the DataAdapter.
                database1DataSet.tblReject_test.Clear();
                rdDataAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);
            }
            catch (OleDbException exc)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnLoadChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                int count = database1DataSet.Tables["tblReject_test"].Rows.Count;

                DataConnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = DataConnection;
                string query = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.AddXY(reader["reject_category"].ToString(), reader[count].ToString());
                }

                DataConnection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the connection string ? From the error description, it seems that you are missing the connection string in connection.

Comment: Lemme edit the post quickly and I will show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wouldn't compile as you are assigning a string to DataConnection (instance of OleDbConnection).

The correct usage should be as following.

```
string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";

DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring));
```

Also, your code doesn't close Database connection in case of exception.
It would be recommended to use the code as shown below. This is taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0ckc7ak%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("DataSource: {0} \nDatabase: {1}",
                connection.DataSource, connection.Database);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
    }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed response.

I tried the correct usage above and I get an error saying:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' to 'string'.

Comment: You need to remove the line string DataConnection; from method private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). As you have declared Dataconnection already as a member variable of the class.

Comment: I had to move the connection lines into the load chart button to get the chart to load, however I still have the problem of trying to set it up so that it counts the number of times a record pops up in the dataset/table.

Comment: is that an issue with Charts or with a SQL query ?